# Override method in derived class cpp

Tags: c++

So I have an abstract class (A) with a method that takes a parameter of type A and return a parameter of type A.

Now, I create a derived class say B. Now I want to override the method defined in A with the parameter and return type to be of type B.

But when I try to do that, I get a compilation error stating that the pure virtual function was not implemented.

Both class A and B are template classes.

```
template<typename VALUE_TYPE>
class A {
  public:
      virtual A<VALUE_TYPE>* ola(const A& other) const = 0;
};
```

```
template  <class T>
class B : public A<T> {
    public:
        B<T>* ola(B<T>& other) {
            return new B<T>;
        }
};
```

Comment: ... because you've likely not implemented in class B the method from class A, but, rather a new method with a different signature.

Comment: I've updated the post with the code. @NicolaeNatea

Answer (score 0):

It should be something along the lines:

```
template<typename VALUE_TYPE>
class A {
  public:
      virtual A<VALUE_TYPE>* ola(const A& other) const = 0;
};
template  <class T>
class B : public A<T> {
    public:
        A<T>* ola(const A<T>& other) const {
            return new B<T>();
        }
};
```

Comment: I see. But for example I have an array in class A, will I be able to create an object of type B, add values to an array and then in the method in B, print that array out?

Comment: B inherits A so depending on the access policy it may access A's members. Then you should consider that A is abstract => you can't really create an instance of A. But for the code that you've posted, the above answer applies.

Comment: you could do something like:   "B<int> abc; B<int> *cde = reinterpret_cast<B<int>*>(abc.ola(abc));" if you know it will return an object of type B, and want to access a specific method that's not available in the base class, but that might look confusing and 'dirthy'.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are changing signature of ola method in class B, virtual override is not going to solve the problem. So why not define different ola method in class B. If you want to access members variable of A, then declare them as protected.

```
class A {
  public:
      A<VALUE_TYPE>* ola(const A& other) const = 0;
  protected:
      <any member you want to access in derived class>
};

template  <class T>
class B: public A<T> {
    public:
        B<T>* ola(B<T>& other) {
            return new B<T>;
        }
};
```

Comment: If I define a different method, I would still need to override the Ola method that exists in A right? I'm just trying to find a way I just have to override the same method and I wouldn't have to do another declaration.

Comment: @Chashmeet So, doesn't the other answer satisfy your need?

Comment: @Chashmeet: You will not have to override as ola in A will not be virtual. If you insist on keeping ola virtual, I would like to question the design itself because in derived class you are looking for ways to change ola signature. Rather than just feasibility, there is a design question also. Mixing template and virtual function is not good idea.